# How to get N index of array from JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

Hi I have JSON file that have users nickname, password and token. I'm using a find function to find users from their nicknames. I want to get tokens too.

```
[
  {
    "user": [
      "bombali",
      "reYiz_2031",
      "GcjSdUMp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": [
      "johndoe",
      "testpasswd1_s",
      "SdNFccRT"
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my JSON data file.

I'm checking if nicname is taken or not using this code:

```
function isUsernameTaken(username) {
  const user_Database = require(`${config.path_users}`);
  const finded_Name = user_Database.find(
    ({ user }) => user[0] === username.toLowerCase()
  );
  if (finded_Name === undefined) {
    console.log("This username is usable");
  } else {
    console.log("This username is unusable");
  }
}
```

Now I want to get token from json by using username and password to use filter. I don't want to use `token:SdNFccRT` in array. Is it possible? Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.filter()` isn't the best choice in this case. With `.find()`, the search will stop once one element has been found, but `.filter()` will keep on going when it doesn't have to.

Given the username and password, you can find the token with a single `.find()` statement that compares each user object's username and password, then returns the token of the match. You can also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to return `undefined` if no match is found. Like this:

```js
const getToken = (data, uname, pass) => data.find(({user}) => user[0] === uname && user[1] === pass)?.user[2];

const data = [{
    "user": [
      "bombali",
      "reYiz_2031",
      "GcjSdUMp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": [
      "johndoe",
      "testpasswd1_s",
      "SdNFccRT"
    ]
  }
];

console.log(getToken(data, 'bombali', 'reYiz_2031'));
console.log(getToken(data, 'none', 'none'));
```

Comment: You're rock mate. Thanks a lot. I'm trying to make ExpressJS like library using freeBSD licence to publish as freeware to everyone. This gonna help a lot!